# Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone

Tags: java, eclipselink

I am facing a common but irritating problem in eclipseLink. I am just trying to run this query using eclipseLink:

List organizationUnitEntityList = entityManager.createQuery("select o from OrganizationUnitEntity o where o.unitId=?1").setParameter(1, userTypeDomain.getUnitId()).getResultList();
OrganizationUnitEntity organizationUnitEntity = organizationUnitEntityList.get(0);

// 1 is passed as parameter

OrganizationUnitEntity is :

public class OrganizationUnitEntity {

```
@Id
private int unitId;
private String unit;

    getters and setters...
```

}

But the exception that I am getting is :
Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone

Now, as there is no null or 0 primary key in the database, why this one is coming??

Comment: Did you check the other tables?  It could be a null or zero PK from a foreign key... maybe?

Comment: No...there is no such case...I have just started developing app and only one entry is there in each table with pk as 1

Answer (score 0):

Where is the exception occuring - you mention you are executing a query, but is it attempting to flush before executing your query?  You can try calling flush before your query as it could be that your EM contains an entity with a 0/null pk when it shouldn't.  If it is occuring after the query, check what results the SQL from the query would return.  Try setting EclipseLink logging to finest:  and if you still have trouble print off what is in the cache using something like: JPAHelper.getEntityManager(em).getActiveSession().getIdentityMapAccessor().printIdentityMaps();